# CRAN Package Submission

Tags: r, package, cran

This is a simple question.
I uploaded my package to CRAN and received the email telling me 
"**CRAN Submission: The following package was uploaded to CRAN**"
And then no more news.

I checked the directory of incoming packages and existing packages. Not found.

Has anyone met with this problem?

Comment: Check https://cransays.itsalocke.com/articles/dashboard.html

Comment: I cannot open this link

Comment: @sunny-song because they moved it here <https://lockedata.github.io/cransays/articles/dashboard.html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have figured this out already but for anyone googling and finding this question in the future because they have the same problem:

It can take up to about 24 hours for the package to actually be on CRAN once it has been published by the employees. If you've checked after one or two days and your package still isn't there, there has probably been a mistake on CRAN's side and your package hasn't actually been published. In this case, email CRAN-submissions@R-project.org and let them know about your problem.